# Solve $x^a = 1 - \exp(-x)$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, transcendental-equations

I would like to obtain a closed-form solution for the equation $x^a = 1 - \exp(-x)$, in which $x$ is the (real strictly positive) unknown and $a$ is a real positive parameter.

So far, I have tried to play around with Lambert W function and with the generalization proposed by Mező and Baricz, and cited in recent posts of this forum (On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics" István Mező, Árpád Baricz http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) but with limited success.

I have no reason to believe that such a closed-form solution exists but, before giving up and going to numeric solvers, I wanted to have your opinion about the existence of a closed-form solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: You can just put $x=0$, can't you?

Comment: @HasanSaad : but you need to prove that its the only solution ;)

Comment: For $a>0$ it is obvious this is the only solution, since $x^a+e^x$ is increasing. @Tryss

Comment: It is as Thomas says (at least the only non-negative solution)

Comment: @Hasan and Thomas: Thanks for your early comments. Will correct a typo ($exp(-x)$) and make clear the interesting solution is strictly positive.

Comment: Also, he said $a$ is a real positive parameter, so I think we're done?

Comment: In general, $x^a$ is not defined for negative real $x$. If $a$ is an even integer, there might be negative solutions.

Comment: He changed the question..

Comment: And now, he's changed the question. Sigh, another poster who does not care about the time of others.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sincere apologies about the change. Be sure I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: I think the proper bound should be $a>1$, not $a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that closed form solution of the positive root of equation $$f(a,x)=x^a -(1 - e^{-x})=0$$ could be obtained.

It seems to me that, beside the trivial $x=0$, the existence of a  positive solution requires $a >1$. In such a case $f(a,0)=0$, $f(a,1)=\frac 1e$. The derivative of the function cancels for $$x_*=(a-1) W\left(\frac 1{(a-1) a^{\frac{1}{a-1}}}\right)<1$$ where appears Lambert function. and this point corresponds to a minimum of the function ($f(a,x_*)<0$).

The positive root is smaller than $1$. Expanding the function as a first order Taylor series around $x=1$, an approximate solution is $$x=\frac{e a-2}{e a-1}$$ Using the simplest Pade approximant would give an estimate of the solution $$x=\frac{\left(e-2 e^2\right) a^2+5 e a-3}{\left(e-2 e^2\right) a^2+3 e a-1}$$ Increasing the degree of denominator, we should get $$x=\frac{\left(e-6 e^2+6 e^3\right) a^3+\left(6 e-18 e^2\right) a^2+17 e a-4}{\left(e-6
   e^2+6 e^3\right) a^3+\left(3 e-12 e^2\right) a^2+8 e a-1} $$ From any of these estimates, Newton method will converge in very few iterations.

For example, for $a=\pi$, the above estimates are respectively $0.867369$, $0.840271$ and $0.835240$ while the solution is $0.834187$.

**Edit**

Rewriting the equation $$a\log(x)=\log(1-e^{-x})$$ and remembering that the solution of $$a\log(x)=b+c x$$ is given by $$x=-\frac{a }{c}W\left(-\frac{c e^{\frac{b}{a}}}{a}\right)$$ we can develop $\log(1-e^{-x})$ as a Taylor expansion at $x=x_0$ to get $$\log(1-e^{-x})=\log
   \left(1-e^{-{x_0}}\right)+\frac{x-x_0}{e^{{x_0}}-1}$$ that is to say  $$b=\log \left(1-e^{-{x_0}}\right)-\frac{{x_0}}{e^{{x_0}}-1}$$ $$c=\frac{1}{e^{{x_0}}-1}$$ and so obtain a very good approximation of the solution using Lambert function.

For example, using $a=\pi$, $x_0=1$, the estimate is $0.838721$ but using $x=\frac{e \pi-2}{e \pi-1}$ the estimate is $0.834420$

Comment: cool. can you get a convergent sequence of bounds like this ? $\displaystyle x^* \in [y_k;z_k]_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ ? it has an application with the riemann zeta function, I don't know it you noticed that. $\zeta(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x -1}dx$, and $\eta(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x + 1} dx$ which converges for $s > 0$, so personnally I'm more interested in a solution of  $x^a = 1+e^x$

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici   Is possible to numerically obtain  numerical solutions for  all $ a > 1 ? $

Comment: @Narasimham. Yes, they are closer and closer to $1$ when $a$ increases

Comment: @reuns. $x^a = 1+e^x$ is a very different problem. What don't you post it ? It looks interesting.